# Can I open CS5 photoshop files in CS4?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5, adobe-cs4

I was wondering if there is a certain way that I have to save my CS5 photoshop file so that it can open up in CS4. I use CS5 at home and at school we use CS4 and I know in Illustrator you have to do that but you just save down and in photoshop I don't see the option to save down.

Answer (score 4):

In Photoshop CS5, go to **Preferences > File Handling > Maximize PSD and PSB file compatibility**, and choose Always or Ask. Then save your file.